# How to handle different types of characters (character's of other languages and special characters) in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my app I am displaying description text which is dynamically received from an api response. So the text my be in different languages' character and may contain some spacial character. How would I handle it in flutter. As I am facing this problem.

> This is the Image showing response in flutter(Look at description key) [image: Look at description key]
>
> Below Image is showing response in postman (Look at description key)[image]

My question is that how I can get same response in flutter as in postman?
I have to display description text as it is appear in postman response.
please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello guys I have solved this problem using dart:Convert package 
response=http.get();
var res=utf8.decode(response.bytedata);